# Using a class once it's properties have been set in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a small class with just a couple properties in it.

here is an example:

```
public class clsRepLogs

public string those;
public string these;

    public void setThoseandThese
    {
    //call a stored procedure
    //get results

    this.those = something;
    this.these   = somethingElse;
    }}
```

from my first.aspx.cs

i call the set function:

```
clsRepLogs cLog - new clsRepLogs()
cLog.setThoseandThese()
```

so now the properties have been assigned values.

i now want to use them in another aspx.cs file to populate a form... but can't figure out how to get to them...

i tried

```
clsRepLogs cLog;

lblThese.text = cLog.these;
```

but it's giving me an error:  "Use of unassigned local variable 'cLog'

basically, how do i tell it to use the values i've already assigned to that class instance from before?

i hope i'm explaining this right, but i might be way of on what i'm doing. any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where you instantiate a copy of clsRepLogs in your second snippet.

Comment: Your class has two fields, not two properties.  There is a significant difference between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to access the same instance of the class from multiple ASPX pages. There are multiple ways to do this; a per-user solution is to use session state.

```
// page 1
var c = new clsRepLogs();
c.setThoseAndThese();
Session["mykey"] = c;

// page 2
var c = (clsRepLogs)Session["mykey"];
```

"mykey" can be any string. You may also want to check if Session contains the value before accessing it, e.g. `if( Session["mykey"] != null ){ ... }`

Keep in mind:

- Session isn't durable; restarting the web worker process will reset all in-process sessions.
- It's usually not a good idea to store many large objects in Session.
- If the data is confidential, be aware of [Session fixation attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation).
- Session can be load balanced across servers, so this solution will scale.

For reference (alternative approaches):

- You could use the `Cache` object when you don't care about per-user isolation and want control over data expiration.
- You could use the `Application` object; similar to `Cache` but no control over expiration.
- You could store the object in the database and load it on each page. This is useful when you to don't want a heavy session, and/or wish to save the data more permanently (such as a shopping cart which persists across multiple sessions).

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize or set `cLog` to the instance of `clsReport` that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't instantiating your class.  It should be

```
clsRepLogs cLog = new clsRepLogs();
```

Or, if I misunderstood your code,

```
clsReport cLog = new clsReport();
```

EDIT:

If you need to preserve these, it should be a static class so that it cannot be instantiated.

```
public static class clsReport
{
    public static string those;
    public static string these;

    public static void setThoseandThese
    {
        //call a stored procedure
        //get results

        this.those = something;
        this.these   = somethingElse;
    }
}
```

A lot of this depends on how you need this to function.  In addition, I'm no expert on perpetuating objects/classes in memory in Webforms applications.  If you wanted to re-access the class to get those values, I'm not sure they would still be in memory.

Comment: but if i say new will it create a whole new instance of the class and overwrite and values, that i've already assigned?

Comment: @TanyaXrum: Not exactly. It will create a new instance that doesn't have anything to do with the previous instance, so the properties will have their default values (null).

Comment: @Tanya your setThoseandThese() method will set the values based on the results of your stored procedure.

Comment: Yes but then you do not need the second assignment that does not initiate an instance I think

Comment: but the values i'm passing into the stored procedure are only available on the first.aspx.cs file, second.aspx.cs file i just wnat to use to populate a form on the screen....

Comment: Please explain the thumbs down.  Thanks!

Comment: Static is not a good solution, when the desired instance can be passed around where needed.

Comment: i didn't do it, i love all help i get :)

Comment: @JGinSD  How would it be passed around in this case?

Comment: The OP hasn't posted enough code to be able to say what way would work for them. But setting it in the session and accessing it from there like Tim Medora suggests would be one way.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialize your cLog class :

```
clsRepLogs cLog = new clsReport();
lblThese.text = cLog.these;
```